# Does browser set the min-height automatically? how to get rid of it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My `HTML` content starts like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

When this page is rendered in **Chrome**[Version 42.0.2311.135 m (up to date)], there is a lot of white space between my content and the footer. The reason was that Chrome renders this page starting like this.
I got this when inspecting via Firebug lite.

```
<html lang="en" debug="true" style="min-height: 667px;">
```

When this page is rendered in **Firefox**[Version 37.0.2(up to date)], there is no extra white space between my content and footer. This is the expected result.

When inspecting via Firebug, I got this,

```
 <html lang="en" style="min-height: 280px;">
```

**Question**: Why different browser is setting the `min-height` automatically differently for the same viewport? how to get rid of it? I mean I don't need that `667px`, so that that white space can be eliminated.

Comment: can you like to share link?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all inline css (in `style` attribute) about height - `height` and `min-height` and use little trick in your css:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I made that change, still the result is same. See the source during inspection `<html lang="en" debug="true" style="min-height: 667px;">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}`

Comment: body still has the min-height as 667  `<body class=" pace-done" style="min-height: 667px;">`

Comment: I even tried by explicitly setting style of body like this `<body style="min-height: 100%;height: auto;">`  but still, the value is overwritten at runtime. ie : `<body style="min-height: 667px; height: auto;" class=" pace-running">`

Comment: Edit answer, remove your inline styles

Answer (score 0):

try normalize css, It makes browsers render all elements more consistently, http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/